# Data not in order while scraping Amazon through jsoup

Tags: java, html, css, web-scraping, jsoup

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bond+nato+strap&crid=3BXLF6SLBX2MN&sprefix=bond+NATO+s%2Caps%2C683&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_10

I am using `jsoup` library to scrape amazon page. I want to get list of `asins` for a particular keyword in proper order as they are in UI.
I am getting the list using this selector but the `asins` are not in order according to the data-index.

```
          Elements resultList = doc.select("#search div.s-result-list div[data-asin]");
          int count = 0;
          for (Element currentProduct : resultList) {
                String asin = currentProduct.attr("data-asin");
                String index = currentProduct.attr("data-index");
                if(asin.isEmpty())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
            
                System.out.println(count + " " + asin + " " + index);
                count++;                   
          }
```

[link to the amazon page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkEYc.png)

`Output:`

`0 B07CZQGHL9 2`
`1 B015ESNT32 3`
`2 B07CZQGHL9 4`
`3 B015ESNT32 5`
`4 B07L748RJ2 6`
`5 B07F4297P9 8`
`6 B07G9W3B8K 9`
`7 B019CXDZAM 10`
`8 B07FWFMX6X 11`
`9 B01BAUVL0Q 12`
`10 B01HQTOX50 13`
`11 B07MQJXR5D 14`
`12 B0838JZ8KY 15`
`13 B071K7J6DW 16`
`14 B071FZ2Q2Z 17`
`15 B01KD8JCBG 18`
`16 B01E62WQTK 19`
`17 B077TF88BS 20`
`18 B0714LW3ZP 21`
`19 B01GEW89P0 22`
`20 B01AF7FA6Q 23`
`21 B074ZVJTS7 24`
`22 B07F3Z9DL7 25`
`23 B073QGQCNV 26`
`24 B073XC1F76 27`
`25 B07ZQTY2H9 28`
`26 B07V9K7DDZ 29`
`27 B073XCZPDQ 30`
`28 B06Y1MQC9Z 31`
`29 B0773X2XJT 32`
`30 B07G9W3B8K 33`
`31 B01AF7FA6Q 34`
`32 B00R2BQFBS 35`
`33 B07VP6YCK9 36`
`34 B07PJL2MXN 37`
`35 B07GJZ1MTP 38`
`36 B07D3GNKM6 39`
`37 B01LZFKETO 40`
`38 B07F42P9VC 41`
`39 B07RY3VNMD 42`
`40 B077Y9NVZJ 43`
`41 B073XF8JV5 44`
`42 B071ZNHV82 45`
`43 B07T7DJTWN 46`
`44 B073XC7QYY 47`
`45 B081B7HCP4 48`
`46 B01KD8J7OI 49`
`47 B077M7LDNT 50`
`48 B00N65QE8I 51`
`49 B00EF1KODI 52`
`50 B00N65R900 53`
`51 B07QX5X3Q2 54`
`52 B07NS7ZDD5 55`
`53 B006R2N3FE 56`
`54 B01MUA2CX6 57`
`55 B00N65RRMU 58`
`56 B07DJ7QLQ6 59`
`57 B0756B75MK 60`
`58 B01GEW89P0 61`
`59 B00R2BQKQ8 62`

I compared the above `output` with the list of asins which are inside this selector `div.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row` on amazon page. I am getting the `asins` in random order and some of the asins which are in this list are not in UI. I don't know why this is happening. I tried this with `puppeteer` also but still getting same results. Tried with proxy also but still no luck.

Then I tried another way in which I used `selectors` for individual `asins` and put them in an `arraylist`.

```
    Elements ist = doc.select("#search > div.s-desktop-width-max.s-desktop-content.sg-row > div.sg-col-20-of-24.sg-col-28-of-32.sg-col-16-of-20.sg-col.sg-col-32-of-36.sg-col-8-of-12.sg-col-12-of-16.sg-col-24-of-28 > div > span:nth-child(4) > div.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row > div:nth-child(3)");
      String asin = ist.attr("data-asin");
      String index = ist.attr("data-index");
      System.out.println("ist: " + asin +" index: " + index);
```

But the result was totally unexpected by this way also. I want to get this resultlist in exact order as they are in UI for every keyword. My main goal is to get only `top 5 asins(products)` for every keyword.

Comment: It may be something to do with the way doc is obtained?. Are you using urls? requests? . Selenium will be a better option in this case.

Comment: **Selenium** is what I said to him.  I don't understand your point at all.  The data you have posted is ***ordered almost perfectly***  You have not clarified what is missing, or shown a copy from the `View Source` button of the data ***you wee NOT able to retrieve***.  The numbers ***are sorted*** - can you really not see that?